# Async await one of many

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Is there a way to perform an async await on a group of promises, but only await the first completion?

For example:

```
async function run() {
    const ms = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function test() {
    await Promise.first([run(), run(), run(), run(), run()]); // first or similar?

    // this line would be reached after the first run() finished execution
    // receieve results from first completion
}
```

Comment: You can call the first `run` on its own.

Comment: In the example, the first run() may have a timeout of 900ms, whereas for example the fourth one may have a timeout of 100ms. In this case, the goal is to await until the fastest is complete (likely the fourth one in this case) and return the results from that Promise. Apologies if my explanations aren't the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Promise.race`.

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one');
});

var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'two');
});

Promise.race([promise1, promise2]).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // Both resolve, but promise2 is faster
});
// expected output: "two"
```

More Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

Comment: Glad it helps :)